# Python 3 String Insertion from Dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm trying to update some code from python 2 notation to python 3 notation. The code inserts into a string from a dictionary. In python 2, this looks like:

```
string = "Today I saw a %(animal)s at the park."
ex_dict = {"animal": "dog"}
mod_string = string % ex_dict
print mod_string
```

which would result in

```
Today I saw a dog at the park.
```

I tried the updated notation using the `.format` insertion:

```
string = "Today I saw a {} at the park."
mod_string = string.format(ex_dict)
print(mod_string)
```

which gives the unwanted result:

```
Today I saw a {'animal': 'dog'} at the park.
```

What is the proper way to replace the `%s %` notation with the `{}.format()` notation in this case?

Comment: `"Today I saw a {animal} at the park.".format(**ex_dict)` or `"Today I saw a {animal} at the park.".format_map(ex_dict)`

Comment: That works beautifully! Thank you so much!